# How to profile a Nest.js application by using node CLI command?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, nestjs, profiling, webstorm

I has been developing a Nest.js application for a REST API server, and I want to do some performance analysis by using Node.js profiling tools.
I know that there are several tools like WebStorm V8 CPU and Memory Profiling (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/v8-cpu-and-memory-profiling.html#node_profiling_before_you_start) and node CLI option `--prof`.

However, I don't know how to start my Nest.js application by using `node` CLI program, so I don't know how to apply these profiling tools to my Nest.js application.

Is there any way to use Node.js profiling tools to Nest.js application? Or is there any other good solutions for Nest.js application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could build the application using `nest build` and then run it using `node --prof dist/main`. Or you could just use `nest start --watch -e 'node --prof'` which should tell Nest to use `node --prof dist/main` for the start command

Comment: Ah... It was a lot easier than I thought. I was just thinking of using `nest start --watch`. Thank you :)